# How to set Node Attributes on a Chef Client?

Tags: chef-infra

I'm using the [chef-client cookbook](https://github.com/opscode/cookbooks/tree/master/chef-client) to configure a machine as a chef client . How do I configure node attributes when this client is created ?

I do not want to do `knife node edit` . My aim is to set some node attributes when creating this node, probably by adding something to a JSON file.

UPDATE:

I am creating hundreds of nodes which will use this script ([see the gist](https://gist.github.com/4076949)) to bootstrap chef-clients.  Node_name which is in the script will be different for each node. Similarly I want to set a custom attribute to the node that will group them together.

Say for example I want to group all the nodes belonging to a particular project together. I was thinking I will add an attribute "project_id" to the Node. So that I can search later for all nodes belonging to a project. This is especially useful for deployments - while trying to find out all db_master roles / webserver roles / memcached roles belonging to a particular project .

So what I want to do is this : there should be some placeholder in the script (which you saw in the gist) where I can add custom attributes like project_id or whatever to the Node. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 4):

Both the above work or you can create them in recipes using something like

```
Node[attribute_name]
```

To keep with your json functionality you could leverage attributes or tags

to add attributes use something like this in your json file that you're generating. The attribute name and value can be generated in your script by parameters or csv/xml input

```
{

    "test_attribute" : "testvalue"
}
```

In the example you've linked to they are setting attributes under a chef-client hash

```
"chef_client": {
 "server_url": "http://ec2-23-20-173-176.compute-1.amazonaws.com:4000",
 "interval": "20"
}
```

Those attributes are created as normal node attributes and would be accessed by `node["chef_client"]["interval"]` for example.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I've updated the question with details of what I'm trying to achieve . Please see the "UPDATE" section of the question. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer Emil. Think it's more like what you were looking for

Comment: I tried that too , didn't work for me. The reason, I think, is this - the json file is used for chef-solo, so any node attribute set using that will not persist after the chef-solo run(please correct me if I'm wrong). chef-solo will create `/etc/chef/client.rb` and start chef-client as a daemon using this new file as the config. You can see the [chef-client cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/chef-client). Looks like the recipe doesn't allow setting custom attributes.

Comment: I'm running on open source chef server. Using the -j file did persist the node information on the server for me hmmm.. One thing I did notice was it was only persisted after a fully completed succesful run of the chef-client. So to bring it back to the desired result what are you attempting to do in terms of setting attributes. Do you want to use them in this recipe or other recipes?

Comment: I know this is old, however to clarify, the answer is correct.  In order to add in an attribute override for chef-solo you would add in the -j parameter but you do NOT use "default_attribute", "override_attribute", etc. as the warning in https://docs.chef.io/chef_solo.html alludes to, but is not clear at all.  You simply put the attribute as a sibling to the the "run_list" attribute.

In addition, you DO need to provide this -j flag each time you run chef-solo or you need to customize the client.rb to point to the file via json_attributes

Answer (score 1):

Either give the client a role and add attributes there or pass a .json file containing node data using the -j parameter of chef-client.

Comment: Here's [a gist](https://gist.github.com/4076949) of what I'm doing to create the chef-client. What do I change there to set an attribute , say "foo_attribute" : "bar_value" to the node ?

Comment: I've updated the question with details of what I'm trying to achieve . Please see the "UPDATE" section of the question. Thanks.

Answer (score -4):

Lets say you want to add the recipe mouse to your node target1.

```
knife node run_list add target1 "recipe[mouse]"
```

It should work with all the attributes.

Comment: The question was how to add node attributes, not how to add recipe’s to a node’s run list.